# blank space between ListView and BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a blank space between `BottomNavigationBar` and `ListView` which I want to get rid of.

I tried using `Expanded` instead of `Flexible`, but in the case of `Expanded` I can't control the height proportion between Widget produced by _adher() and DrugsListView()

[image]

```
new Container(
       child: new Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           Flexible(
             flex: 1,
             child: _adher(),
           ),
           Flexible(
             flex: 2,
             child:DrugsListView(),
           ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
```

Comment: For an explanation of asking a better question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The code snippet is not enough, can you post the complete code of your screen.

Comment: The problem is here

Comment: are you using any padding...also kindly add more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Add fit FlexFit.tight parameter

we simply add fit parameter`FlexFit.tight` because by default, flexible will set
fit as `FlexFit.loose`.

```dart
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      fit: FlexFit.tight, // add this line
      child: _adher(),
    ),
    Flexible(
      flex: 2,
      fit: FlexFit.tight, // add this line
      child: DrugsListView(),
    ),
  ],
),
```

### 2. Demo

[image: Demo]

### 3. For full Repo

You may look into this repo and build it locally. [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout/blob/master/lib/h_screen/float_bottom_bar.dart)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `Flexible()` to `Expanded()` widget instead.

```
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: _adher(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: DrugsListView(),
    ),
  ],
),
```